# How to create Diamond shape Button using Objective-C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, core-graphics

I need to design diamond shape buttons like below image. I have tried with two `UIViews` and I'm able to draw diamond shape on top of the views by subclassing the `UIView`.But the problem is these two views are overlapping..!

Here is the method i have used :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, 
      [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150, 150);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 200);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50, 150);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are those two diamonds are in one view or in two separate views ?

Comment: Bohe are Separate Views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily transform a square to a diamond. Assuming that you have a sqaure button called diamond the transfomation below results in a diamond.

```
CGAffineTransform tr = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
tr = CGAffineTransformScale(tr, 0.8, 1);
tr = CGAffineTransformRotate(tr, M_PI_4);
self.diamond.transform = tr;
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I thought of this after I posted my answer, so I'm glad you added it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid the overlapping of the views. Views are rectangular shaped!

What you *can* do is avoid the tappability of the area outside the diamond drawing. You would do that by munging the hit-testing for these buttons, so that button is "touched" only if the user taps inside the diamond.

Comment: even though we mask the uiview to some custom bezier path(circle) using cashapelayer, are they still be rectangular view ?

Comment: @Mr.T of course. If you then set the `backgroundColor` of that view, you'll see the rectangular region that the `frame` occupies. That's just how the UIKit coordinate system works (with frames, not vertices). If OP really only wanted 4 vertices in a diamond shape, he'd have to go for a lower level API than UIKit (Open GL or Metal). But the easiest solution as matt says is just to integrate custom hit-testing logic to the views.

Comment: If you check the attached picture at my answere, you can see the backgroundColor with green. However the frame of the button is still a rectangular area, this has no effect on hit testing. The button will respond to a tap event if that is inside the green area.

Comment: @fabe Agreed, that's a good alternative in this particular case. But wouldn't be so easy if the shape to be tapped on were some irregular or curved shape! Thus what I'm saying is still the _general_ solution.

Answer (score 0):

this is what is look like in swift in case anyone wondering

`var tr = CGAffineTransformIdentity
tr = CGAffineTransformScale(tr, 0.8, 1)
tr = CGAffineTransformRotate(tr, M_PI_4)
self.diamond.transform = tr`

but the problem is that the text also effected by it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5D4p.png)